# android dispatchTouchEvent get tapped view

Tags: android, events

I call this function in my activity :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent)
```

That allows me to process action before any components get focused or even deny the focus to these elements.

**PROBLEM** : I was wondering how I could know what component (View) has been touched in this function, then I could choose if I want to consumme the event or not.

**UGLY SOLUTION** : I'm currently having an ugly solution which is : I know the position of the component that is allowed to get the event, and I do a plenty of condition to approximately decide if the user clicked on this component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `OnTouchListener`

```
private OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener= new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

          switch(v.getId()){

              case R.id.id1): 
              // Do stuff
              break;

              case R.id.id2: 
              // Do stuff
              break;
              }    

        return false/true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Would be a good solution. Unfortunatly, for some reasons (bad code, bad structure, ...), when I put this function on the root element and I set its descendantFocusability to before descendant, It just doesn't go in this function. In summarize, I can't get it work, but I won't spam with my 3000 code line. I was just looking for an other solution.

Comment: To use it, you should add this listener to all views of a current fragment.

Answer (score -1):

view.getid==R.id.//id in layout// condition can be checked for the required view is clicked